# A Serious Case of For-Each Loop Confusion

Tags: java, loops, foreach

I have a program that extracts data from a text file and stores it in two different arrays like this:

```
public void extractDataIntoArray() {
    array = new ArrayList<String>();    
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        s.useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
        array.add(s.next());
    }
  }

  public void extractDataIntoArray2() {
        array2 = new ArrayList<String>();   
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            s.useDelimiter("Event=|,(.)+[\\r\\n]*Event=|,(.)+[\\r\\n]*");
            array2.add(s.next());
        }
  }
```

I want to take the first element from each array and create an Event with it. I've had some success by creating the events and getting them to print to the console,  but they should be printing to the console with a staggered delay based on the "l" value that is being passed into the method `createSpecificEvent()`. The events print to screen instantly, so I think my for-each loop is wrong and it's passing a "0" into each `createSpecificEvent()` instance.

```
public void action() {
    openFile();                     // grab file with Scanner
    extractDataIntoArray();         // extract values from text value and put in array

    for (String  e : array) {              
        long l = Long.parseLong(e); // for each value in array, convert to long and set to l

        openFile();                     // grab file with Scanner...
        extractDataIntoArray2();        // extract values from text file and put in array2

        for (String  e2 : array2) {
            event = createSpecificEvent(e2, l);
            //System.out.println(event);
            addEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what my `createSpecificEvent()` code looks like:

```
public Event createSpecificEvent(String eventName, long delayTime) {
    Event event = null;

    switch(eventName) {
    case "ThermostatNight": 
        event = new ThermostatNight(delayTime);
        break;
    case "ThermostatDay": 
        event = new ThermostatDay(delayTime);
        break;
    case "LightOn": 
        event = new LightOn(delayTime);
        break;
    case "LightOff": 
        event = new LightOff(delayTime);
        break;
    case "WaterOn":
        event = new WaterOn(delayTime);
        break;
    case "WaterOff": 
        event = new WaterOff(delayTime);
        break;
    case "Bell": 
        event = new Bell(delayTime);
        break;
    case "FansOn": 
        event = new FansOn(delayTime);
        break;
    case "FansOff": 
        event = new FansOff(delayTime);
        break;
    case "Terminate": 
        event = new Terminate(delayTime);
        break;
    }

    return event;
}
```

Here is what my text file looks like:

```
Event=ThermostatNight,time=0
Event=LightOn,time=2000
Event=WaterOff,time=10000
Event=ThermostatDay,time=12000
Event=Bell,time=9000,rings=5
Event=WaterOn,time=6000
Event=LightOff,time=4000
Event=Terminate,time=20000
Event=FansOn,time=7000
Event=WindowMalfunction,time=15000
Event=FansOff,time=8000
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
Restarting system
Thermostat on night setting
Light is on
Greenhouse water is off
Thermostat on day setting
Bing!
Greenhouse water is on
Light is off
Terminating
```

The first line should print instantly and the last line should print after 20 seconds.

Comment: Did you try to print `l` inside the loop so you can be sure it's always `0` ??

Comment: Just tried. It prints 0 eleven times and then moves on to the next number which is 2000 and prints it eleven times and so on. So, it is just using 0 for for all the events because I only have eleven events

Comment: can you show us the content of the file you read ? there might be an error in the way you extract strings from it.

Comment: See edit for createSpecificEvent

Comment: T-D: I printed the arrays after extracting the data and it is the correct data.

Comment: It's correct ? you mean there were no zeros in the data ?

Comment: See edit for the text file

Comment: Now I can see why , you are executing the second loop eleven time all for only the first value of the first loop which is zero, I'll give you a correction for this ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public void action() {

 openFile();                     // grab file with Scanner
 extractDataIntoArray();         // extract values from text value and put in array

 openFile();                     // grab file with Scanner...
 extractDataIntoArray2();        // extract values from text file and put in array2

 for(int i = 0; i < array.size() ;i++)
 {
    long l = Long.parseLong(array.get(i)); 

    string e2 = array2.get(i);
    event = createSpecificEvent(e2, l);
    addEvent(event);

    if(e2.equals("Terminate"))
     {
       break;
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 11, Size: 11

Comment: the size of the output you mentioned in the question is 9 not 11, can you explain why? I'm not sure what should the output be?

Comment: If you are not expecting an output of size more than 9, you can simply change the condition in the `for` loop into `i < 9`

Comment: My output size will range because I have several text files that I need to read from

Comment: I want it so the file path is the only thing I have to change.

Comment: Ok I can see , I think you're getting the exception because the size of the first array is 11 while the size of the second one is less (may be 10) , could do you explain why the output is stopping at Terminating ? Because it looks like the elements of the second array are all the strings in the file before the string `"Terminating"`

Comment: Terminate exits the program. However, it should occur last at 20000 milliseconds. So that's why the other 3 that follow terminate in the text file weren't printing with my original code

Comment: so you just have to put an `if` condition inside the loop to avoid the exception since you don't need to print any other results after `"Terminating"`, see the update of my answer.

Comment: @LooMeenin P.S : don't use `==` to compare string , use `.equals(anotherString)` instead as in my last edit

Comment: It's almost working. The output is now staggering. However, I am only getting 3 events and then it terminates.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42923/discussion-between-t-d-and-loomeenin)

Answer (score 1):

You're running one loop inside another.

You should probably run `extractDataIntoArray()` and `extractDataIntoArray2()` first, then run the loop over one of the arrays and use both values in a single loop, as shown by T-D.

The problem you encountered is most likely with the implementation of your data extraction methods. If they are pulling from the same file, they should actually be one method, and you should only have to open/read the file one time. As it is they seem to be producing arrays of different lengths!